# Exporting MySQL database table to multiple files and import huge Dataset in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

Exporting Data MySQL

In MySQL PHP admin database I have multiple table. I want to run a SQL script/query, so I can export all the database table into different XML, CSV or Text file formant exactly the same structure I have it in my database.

In XMAPP I can export each table into different format (xml, csv or text), but since I have many tables, hence the automatic way exporting many files will be convenient and time efficient.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you use phpmyadmin? it's installed with xampp.. go to localhost/phpmyadmin, login, export your tables!

Comment: @Prasanth I have many tables and manually exported them require a huge time, thats why I'm looking for if there is any faster way by running script or query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool, described here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html

A simple export is done like this:

```
mysqldump -p - -user=username dbname tableName > tableName.sql
```

Importing like this:

```
mysql -u username -p -D dbname < tableName.sql
```